# JQuery UI 1.10.3 Sortable not removing items

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using a sortable div of images, but i'm not able to remove the item when it gets dragged out of the div.

```
    var sortableIn = false;
    $("#divId").sortable({
        over: function () {
            sortableIn = false;
        },
        out: function () {
            sortableIn = true;
        },
        beforeStop: function () {
            if (sortableIn == true) {
                ui.item.remove();
            }
        },
    }).disableSelection();
```

I have also tried $(div.img) with the remove method in the beforeStop function I know $(div.img) is not correct but it does seem to remove the annoying placeholder that was popping up.
var newItem = ui.item; also didnt do the trick.

[image]

And here is the annoying placehold[image]er

Comment: Possible bug with jQuery UI 1.10.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/hdmZY/

I used

```
var sortableIn = false;
$('#divId').sortable({ 
    over: function () {
            sortableIn = false;
        },
    out: function (event, ui) {
            sortableIn = true;
        },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) { 
        if (sortableIn == true) {
          ui.item.remove(); 
          }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Just noticed that your example is using jQuery 1.8.3, and it seems to be working on JSFiddle atleast with jQuery 1.9.1 and UI 1.9.2.

Comment: No you are correct , im going blind.. was missing the event and ui parameters in my functions